Downgrade to old kernel in ubuntu
I'm trying to downgrade my Ubuntu kernel version from 6.5.0-27-generic to either 4.4.0-51-generic, 4.4.0-47-generic, 4.4.0-36-generic, or 4.4.0-47-generic #68~14.04.1-Ubuntu. I've attempted several methods but haven't been successful so far.
Could someone please provide step-by-step instructions on how to downgrade to any of the mentioned kernel versions?
purpose:
establish Linux Kernel 4.4.0 (Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 x86-64) - 'AF_PACKET' Race Condition Privilege Escalation attack in my virtual machine

Only fully supported releases of Ubuntu (standard support) are on-topic for this site.  Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is in extended support and now Ubuntu 14.04 ESM thus only supported by Canonical via Ubuntu Advantage and off-topic here.  Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/05/02/ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-reached-end-of-life-on-april-25-2019-esm-available/

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's standard support life thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm  This is community support; 16.04 is EOSS thus out of community support.

I would recommend you instead install Ubuntu 16.04.7 in a sandbox for your testing purposes - of course knowing that this release has security vulnerabilities.
https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/
It may be necessary for you to compile the vulnerable kernel yourself (it seems the latest release has patched the vulnerability with the installed kernel).

sure i will test in this version. thank you for your response
